# Dismissed view empties before animation starts when using SwiftUI navigation in combination with TCA

Tags: animation, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-sheet, swift-composable-architecture

We are struggling with SwiftUI navigation in combination with TCA and I am wondering is someone else did encounter similar issue.

The problem is that when we set parameters `isPresented` or `isActive` on `.sheet` or `NavigationLink` to `false` to dismiss it, then all content seems to be replaced with empty view before the animation starts (see attached gif).

In the code we store state (boolean value) indicating if child view is presented in parent view. When button to go back on child view is tapped, then we catch this action in parent view and change the boolean value to `false` to dismiss child view. It works like a charm instead of navigation animation.

I would be endlessly happy for any help or suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Maybe true holding onto the state parameter a little longer

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. My example is a bit more involved but arguably more generic. Hope it helps.

My TCA setup looks like this:

```swift
struct State: Equatable {
    var child: ChildState?
    // ...
}
```

One can get the child store by scoping the parent store:

```swift
let childStore = parentStore.scope { $0.child ?? ChildState() }
```

And the child view’s `body` looks like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    WithViewStore(childStore) { viewStore in
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here is what happened:

1. Some reducer sets `parent.child = nil`.
2. This notifies every scoped store that the root state changes.
3. Each scoped store then applies the scope function to get a new child state, and compares it with the previous one. More likely than not, we get a different child state. Some `objectWillChange` is called.
4. The corresponding `WithViewStore` is marked dirty.
5. The content closure in `WithViewStore` is called, and generates a new child view tree.
6. SwiftUI then generates an animation from the old child view tree to the new child view tree, in addition to the dismissal animation for the whole child view tree.

My solution is to kill step 3. First, let's extend the child state with another property:

```swift
struct ChildState: Equatable {
    var isBeingDismissed: Bool = false
}
```

Second, when scoping, let's do:

```swift
let childStore = parentStore.scope { x -> ChildState in
    if let child = x.child {
        return child
    }
    var child = ChildState()
    child.isBeingDismissed = true
    return true
}
```

Lastly, we can modify the `WithViewStore` with a custom `removeDuplicates` closure:

```swift
var body: some View {
    WithViewStore(childStore) { old, new in 
        if old == new {
            return true
        }
        // Key
        if new.isBeingDismissed {
            return true
        }
        return false
    } content: { viewStore in
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here is how it works. The scoped child state can be `nil` in two cases, when the view is first created and the view is being dismissed. In the first case, the old is `nil`. In the second case, the new is `nil`. The custom `removeDuplicates` essentially does this: when a child state is being dismissed, we skip any update. So the only animation being played is the transition animation. The content stays the same.